# a very chill kid

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have seen this phrase in an article. I looked up the word "chill" but there are no definition that fitted in that phrase or maybe I can't imagine what ***a very chill kid*** like.

> When Justin Steece ventures out of his apartment in Wuhan, his primary
>   worry isn’t getting sick. He’s more concerned that he might bring the
>   deadly pneumonia-like virus circulating the city back home to his wife
>   and newborn baby. But with supplies of infant formula getting low,
>   Steece doesn’t have much of a choice.
>
> “He’s ***a very chill kid*** and doesn’t cry much unless he’s hungry,”
>   Steece, 26, from Lake George, Minn., who works as a teacher in Wuhan,
>   tells TIME. “My biggest fear is that I’ll go out and accidentally
>   transmit the disease to my family.”

Source : https://time.com/5773546/americans-trapped-wuhan-coronavirus/

Comment: Relaxed, content, in more informal settings: “fun to be around with”.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, it means *calm* or *relaxed*.

*Chill person* is used quite frequently, there's even an explanation on *How to be a chill person* in the **WikiHow** (please read more [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Be-Chill)):

> Do you want to be that chill person in your friend group that never
>   sweats the small stuff and just enjoys their life? It can seem hard
>   but it's really not! Read the directions below to get some great ideas
>   for chilling out and making the most out of your life.

But since every kid is a **person**, you can apply the explanation for a *chill person* to a *chill kid* as well.

Answer (score 1):

The article clarifies the choice of wording with what follows: “doesn’t cry much unless he’s hungry”. *Chill* in this context means the baby is usually calm and not upset.

Compare these related slang expressions:

- **[chill out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chill%20out)**: “to calm down : go easy : RELAX —often used in the imperative”
- **[take a chill pill](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+chill+pill)**
  “To calm down; to stop being angry, anxious, fearful, etc. Usually used as an imperative.” (To clarify, this is an idiom and not a suggestion to do drugs.)